# Java regex expression to sanitize an uploaded file name

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to sanitize a String that contains an uploaded file's name. I'm doing this because the files will be downloaded from the web and, plus, I want to normalize the names. This is what I have so far:

```
private String pattern = "[^0-9_a-zA-Z\\(\\)\\%\\-\\.]";

//Class methods & stuff

private String sanitizeFileName(String badFileName) {
    StringBuffer cleanFileName = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher fileMatcher = filePattern.matcher(badFileName);
    boolean match = fileMatcher.find();
    while(match) {
        fileMatcher.appendReplacement(cleanFileName, "");
        match = fileMatcher.find();
    }
    return cleanFileName.substring(0, cleanFileName.length() > 250 ? 250 : cleanFileName.length());         
}
```

This works ok, but for a strange reason the extension of the file is erased. i.e. "p%Z_-...#!$()=¡¿&+.jpg" ends up being "p%Z_-...()".

Any Idea as to how should I tune up my regex?

Comment: After posting the question I started wondering why didn't I use replaceAll...

Comment: I was going to say that replaceAll is what I would use in this situation.

Comment: The code above can be boiled down to a two-liner by using `replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z\\+\\.\\(\\)_\\-]","")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Matcher#appendTail at the end of your loop.

Comment: Indeed, the appendTail did the trick. Silly me :). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One line solution:

```
return badFileName.replaceAll("[^0-9_a-zA-Z\\(\\)\\%\\-\\.]", "");
```

If you want to restrict it to just alphanumeric and space:

```
return badFileName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
```

Cheers :)